# ipyleaflet map moves every time a marker is added

Tags: python, leaflet, folium, ipyleaflet

i am trying to create a map which is updated continuously with received data and I have a problem.
the map moves everytime a new marker is added and it is making it useless as it should be zoomed to get more detail. i dont know what is the problem when i test a simple 3 marker map it doesnt move, but when i create a function to update the map it moves to the latest added marker.

this is my simple code that doesn't move(works correctly):

cell1:

```
from ipyleaflet import Marker, DivIcon, Map, LegendControl


def create_triangle_icon(max_intensity, scaling_factor, font_size, font_family, border_color, background_color, text_color):


    html = f"""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Equilateral Triangle</title>
    <style>
      .equilateral-triangle {{
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: {25 * scaling_factor}px solid transparent;
        border-right: {25 * scaling_factor}px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: {43.3 * scaling_factor}px solid {border_color}; /* Hex color: {border_color} */
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }}
      .equilateral-triangle::after {{
        content: "{max_intensity:.1f}";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -{50 * scaling_factor}px; /* Adjust the vertical position of the text as needed */
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        color: {text_color}; /* Text color */
        font-size: {font_size}px; /* Font size */
        font-family: {font_family}; /* Font family */
      }}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="equilateral-triangle"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    return html


def create_star_icon(color, size, Mw):
    html = f"""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Star Icon</title>
    <style>
      .star-container {{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: {size}px;
        height: {size}px;
      }}
      .five-point-star {{
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-right: {size * 2}px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: {size * 1.5}px solid {color};
        border-left: {size * 2}px solid transparent;
        transform: rotate(37deg);
      }}
      .five-point-star:before {{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: -{size * 0.78}px;
        left: -{size}px;
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-bottom: {size * 1.12}px solid {color};
        border-left: {size * 0.37}px solid transparent;
        border-right: {size * 0.37}px solid transparent;
        transform: rotate(323deg);
      }}
      .five-point-star:after {{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: -{size * 2}px;
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-right: {size * 2}px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: {size * 1.5}px solid {color};
        border-left: {size * 2}px solid transparent;
        transform: rotate(286deg);
      }}
      .star-text {{
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        bottom: -10px; /* Adjust the vertical position of the text as needed */
        font-size: 12px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="star-container">
      <div class="five-point-star"></div>
      <div class="star-text">{Mw}</div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    return html


def create_triangle_icon2(max_intensity, scaling_factor, font_size, font_family):
    if max_intensity < 3:
        border_color = "#e7edff"
        background_color = '#e7edff'  # cyan
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 3 <= max_intensity < 3.5:
        border_color = "#b1fff2"
        background_color = '#b1fff2'  # green
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 3.5 <= max_intensity < 4:
        border_color = "#7cffe9"
        background_color = '#7cffe9'  # Yellow  8ef1ff  00d1ef
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 4 <= max_intensity < 4.5:
        border_color = "#00d1ef"
        background_color = '#00d1ef'  # red
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 4.5 <= max_intensity < 5:
        border_color = "#efff91"
        background_color = '#efff91'  # red
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 5 <= max_intensity < 5.5:
        border_color = "#f8e29f"
        background_color = '#f8e29f'  # red
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 5.5 <= max_intensity < 6:
        border_color = "#f8c38d"
        background_color = '#f8c38d'  # red
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 6 <= max_intensity < 6.5:
        border_color = "#e68787"
        background_color = '#e68787'  # red
        text_color = 'white'
    elif 6.5 <= max_intensity < 7:
        border_color = "#b36189"
        background_color = '#b36189'  # red
        text_color = 'white'
    else:
        border_color = "#6c4259"
        background_color = '#6c4259'  # darkpurple #9300FF
        text_color = 'white'
        
    html = f"""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Equilateral Triangle{max_intensity}</title>
    <style>
      .equilateral-triangle{max_intensity:} {{
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: {25 * scaling_factor}px solid transparent;
        border-right: {25 * scaling_factor}px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: {43.3 * scaling_factor}px solid {border_color}; /* Hex color: {border_color} */
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }}
      .equilateral-triangle{max_intensity}::after {{
        content: "{max_intensity:.1f}";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -{50 * scaling_factor}px; /* Adjust the vertical position of the text as needed */
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        color: {text_color}; /* Text color */
        font-size: {font_size}px; /* Font size */
        font-family: {font_family}; /* Font family */
      }}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="equilateral-triangle{max_intensity}"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    return html


Mw = 4.5
center = (52.204793, 360.121558)
max_intensity = 6  # You can adjust this value to change the appearance of the triangle
scaling_factor = 0.7  # You can adjust this factor to scale the triangle
font_size = 16  # You can adjust the font size of the max_intensity
font_family = "Arial, sans-serif"  # You can adjust the font family of the max_intensity
star_color = "#FFA500"  # Hexadecimal color for orange
star_icon_size = 10




html = create_triangle_icon2(max_intensity, scaling_factor, font_size, font_family)
html2 = create_triangle_icon2(4, scaling_factor, font_size, font_family)
html_star = create_star_icon(star_color, star_icon_size, Mw)

m = Map(center=center, zoom=10)
icon = DivIcon(html=html, bg_pos=[0, 0], icon_size=[0, 0])
mark = Marker(location=center, icon=icon)
m.add_layer(mark)

icon2 = DivIcon(html=html2, bg_pos=[0, 0], icon_size=[0, 0])
mark2 = Marker(location=(52.414793, 360.431558), draggable=False, icon=icon2)
m.add_layer(mark2)


# Adding Star Marker
icon_star = DivIcon(html=html_star, bg_pos=[0, 0], icon_size=[0, 0])
mark_star = Marker(location=(52.404793, 360.421558), icon=icon_star)
m.add_layer(mark_star)
# Manipulate the legend
legend = LegendControl({"<3": "#e7edff", "3-3.5": "#b1fff2", "3.5-4": "#7cffe9", "4-4.5": "#00d1ef", "4.5-5": "#efff91",
                        "5-5.5": "#f8e29f", "5.5-6": "#f8c38d", "6-6.5": "#e68787", "6.5-7": "#b36189",
                        ">7": "#6c4259"}, title="IMI", position="topright")

m.add(legend)
m
```

and then when I execute these cells it doesn't move.

Cell2:

```
icon2 = DivIcon(html=html2, bg_pos=[0, 0], icon_size=[0, 0])
mark2 = Marker(location=(52.614793, 360.631558), draggable=False, icon=icon2)
m.add_layer(mark2)
```

but the when i create a code which uses a function to update the map. it moves to the latest added marker.

here is the code:
Cell1:

```
# Create a map
my_map = Map(center=[35.3021392, 51.6328143], zoom=6)

# Display the map
my_map
```

Cell2:

```
rom ipyleaflet import Map, Marker, Popup, DivIcon
from ipywidgets import HTML
import threading
import time

# Function to create HTML for triangle marker with intensity inside
def create_triangle_icon(max_intensity, border_color, background_color, text_color):
    html = f"""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Equilateral Triangle</title>
    <style>
      .equilateral-triangle {{
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 25px solid transparent;
        border-right: 25px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 43.3px solid {border_color}; /* Hex color: {border_color} */
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }}
      .equilateral-triangle::after {{
        content: "{max_intensity}";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -50px; /* Adjust the vertical position of the text as needed */
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        color: {text_color}; /* Text color */
        font-size: 16px; /* Font size */
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Font family */
      }}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="equilateral-triangle"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    return html

# Function to update the map with new markers
def update_map(data):
    all_channel_data = data['all_channel_data']
    max_intensity = max(channel['Intensity'] for channel in all_channel_data)
    
    if max_intensity < 3:
        border_color = "#e7edff"
        background_color = '#e7edff'  # cyan
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 3 <= max_intensity < 3.5:
        border_color = "#b1fff2"
        background_color = '#b1fff2'  # green
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 3.5 <= max_intensity < 4:
        border_color = "#7cffe9"
        background_color = '#7cffe9'  # Yellow  8ef1ff  00d1ef
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 4 <= max_intensity < 4.5:
        border_color = "#00d1ef"
        background_color = '#00d1ef'  # red
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 4.5 <= max_intensity < 5:
        border_color = "#efff91"
        background_color = '#efff91'  # red
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 5 <= max_intensity < 5.5:
        border_color = "#f8e29f"
        background_color = '#f8e29f'  # red
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 5.5 <= max_intensity < 6:
        border_color = "#f8c38d"
        background_color = '#f8c38d'  # red
        text_color = 'black'
    elif 6 <= max_intensity < 6.5:
        border_color = "#e68787"
        background_color = '#e68787'  # red
        text_color = 'white'
    elif 6.5 <= max_intensity < 7:
        border_color = "#b36189"
        background_color = '#b36189'  # red
        text_color = 'white'
    else:
        border_color = "#6c4259"
        background_color = '#6c4259'  # darkpurple #9300FF
        text_color = 'white'
    
    triangle_html = create_triangle_icon(str(round(max_intensity, 1)), border_color, background_color, text_color)
    
    marker = Marker(location=(float(data['latitude']), float(data['longitude'])))
    marker.icon = DivIcon(html=triangle_html, bg_pos=[0, 0], icon_size=[0, 0])
    
    popup_content = f"<b>Intensity:</b> {max_intensity:.1f}"
    popup = Popup(location=marker.location, child=HTML(value=popup_content), close_button=True, auto_close=False, close_on_escape_key=True)
    marker.popup = popup
    
    my_map.add(marker)



import random

# Simulate receiving new data and updating the map
def simulate_data():
    # Generate random latitude, longitude, and intensity values
    latitude = random.uniform(-90, 90)
    longitude = random.uniform(-180, 180)
    intensity = random.uniform(0, 10)
    
    data = {
        'latitude': latitude,
        'longitude': longitude,
        'all_channel_data': [{'Intensity': intensity}]
    }
    update_map(data)

# Simulate receiving new data every 3 seconds
while True:
    simulate_data()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Can anybody help me?

I have no idea what to do here. I tried to split it into two cells but that didn't work. the code I wrote here is the split cells. I'm not familiar with Java script so I have no idea why it moves in one situation but it doesn't move in the other.